# Creating a tree in PHP for search later

Tags: php, apache, tree

```
class BTree
{
    public $root; // the root node of our tree

    public function __construct() {
        $this->root = null;
    }

    public function isEmpty() {
        return $this->root === null;
    }


}
```

I'm creating a BTree above in order to search for names for my webpage. What I'm not sure about is how to keep the tree in order to do a search on it. I have my fronted which calls PHP files, but every time I would want to access a tree I have to recreate it which I do not want to do. How do I have it so the tree gets made once by the server and I can do searches on it?

Comment: put it in your database.

Comment: If you want to retain the tree for multiple calls then you have to persist it, whether in session, or database, or a cache store or similar; or you need to recreate it.... that's the way PHP works

Comment: What do you mean by persist it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)